# Appengine LocalResourceFileServlet no file found for:

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, web.xml

I'm using some in-house tool to upload a config file. But I get the following error:

```
Jan 10, 2013 11:18:58 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /content/xxx.xml
```

Where xxx.xml is the file that I've uploaded. Any hints as to what this erorr means? The class `LocalResourceFileServlet` does not even seem to be present with my vesion of appengine. My hunch is telling me to edit web.xml but I'm not sure...

Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE has a read-only filesystem. So you can not upload a file to appengine and then access it via a direct url. You can only access files that were uploaded as part of the project upload.

However, you can upload file to GAE Blobstore and then access ti via your own handler - see [Blobstore docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview) for examples.