# WARNING: No file found for: /struts/bootstrap/js/validation.min.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine, struts2-jquery

I am using struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.1.jar and struts2-bootstrap-plugin-2.0.0.jar for an application which is running on Appengine.
The jquery validation is failing 
I have the below WARNING message in server console. but Tomcat does not give this WARNING messages

```
            WARNING: No file found for: /struts/js/base/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
            Oct 25, 2014 7:33:28 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
            WARNING: No file found for: /struts/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.min.js
            Oct 25, 2014 7:33:28 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
            WARNING: No file found for: /struts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
            Oct 25, 2014 7:33:28 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
            WARNING: No file found for: /struts/domTT.css
            Oct 25, 2014 7:33:28 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
            WARNING: No file found for: /struts/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
            Oct 25, 2014 7:33:28 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
            WARNING: No file found for: /struts/js/struts2/jquery.struts2.min.js
            Oct 25, 2014 7:33:28 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
            WARNING: No file found for: /struts/domTT.js
            Oct 25, 2014 7:33:28 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
            WARNING: No file found for: /struts/bootstrap/js/validation.min.js
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262542/appengine-localresourcefileservlet-no-file-found-for.